# function(){} and (function(){}) in javascript

Tags: javascript

Team,

I received syntax error when using `function(){}`, but not when `(function(){})`, why? 
I know `(function(){})` is still declaration '`(function(){})()`' is the expression. 
But why this declaration is not possible with simply `function(){}` without covering with `(... )`?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function(){}       //**Syntax error**
(function(){})     //Declaration
(function(){})()   //Expression; so executed.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: `(function(){})` is function expression, not function declaration - that's why function name is optional there.

Comment: @raina77ow no this is different question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have an anonymous function that is assigned to nothing. There is no use since because it is not assigned, you can't call it by a variable name and since it as no name, you can call it by its name.

`(function(){})` will work because the parenthesis are evaluating the function and returning a function reference. You can then call that function with `.call()`, `.apply()` or `()`.

The last one is completly different, it call directly the function. It is the same as the second method, but with a direct call.

List of good function declaration (*ok there is also expressions, shhh*):

```
function name(){};
(function(){}); //Can't call that function latter since it has no reference.
var name = function(){};
var name = (function(){});
var name = function otherName(){};
```